# Move 1Password vault from old Mac to new Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, migration, password

I did a clean install with a new hard drive in my MacBook, with old drive externally connected.

How do I move my 1Password vault from the old drive to the new drive?

- **Is there a single file I can copy?**
- **If no single file approach, will `File` > `Backup` work?**
  I have no idea how to do the restore. When I launch 1Password, it keeps asking for a "Secret Password" as well as a "Master Password". I have a "Master Password", but not a "Secret Password". Their documentation seems to suggest that the "Secret Password" is related to their newer online ongoing accounts. I have no interest in getting an online ongoing account, I only want the local storage option.
- **Is local "syncing" an option?**
  Their documentation web site suggests "synching" a vault to a thumb drive. The doc talks about choosing the thumb drive in a "file browser", but their dialog box for "syncing" shows only a strange bread-crumb style path through several files. There is no way to redirect that bread-crumb path to the thumb drive. So I am stumped by that approach.

At this point I am giving up on 1Password, and just copy-pasting the passwords manually out to a text file. Surely there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's a much simpler way. In fact, you have a number of options, but based on your question I recommend the following:

**On your new Mac**

Do as follows:

1. Install 1Password on your new Mac
2. When it launches the first time you'll see a screen similar to the one below:

[image: screen shot of "Used 1Password before?" dialog box]

3. Select the *More Options...* option to reveal the *Restore from Backup* option.

[image: screen shot of "Used 1Password before?" dialog box, after clicking "More Options…"]

4. Click on the <kbd>Choose Backup...</kbd> button
5. Navigate to where 1Password has saved its automated backups on your old Mac (if your Macs are not networked, then copy the backup onto a Flash drive first and use this for the new Mac)
6. Click the <kbd>Restore</kbd> button

NOTE: As mentioned above there are a number of ways you can do this. You may want to read the [How to move your 1Password data to a new computer or device](https://support.1password.com/new-device/#move-your-data-with-a-usb-flash-drive) for other options.